# Where to keep images of a POS app

Tags: android

I am an android newbie, am developing a POS system for 10" Android Tablet. The images (150 x 150) of the product along with it's names are displayed in a 10 column gridview. There Will be around 1200 images, users can add more products with images. Products are shown based on the product category selected by the user from a listview. Product and product category details are kept in an SQLite db.

I would like to know where to keep these images. Can I keep them on the SD card? or in the SQKite database itself? or do I need a websevice to pull images from a server? If I keep them on the SD card do I need an async task to load the selected products?

Please advise.

Thanks and regards.

Sudheer Palaparambil

Answer (score 0):

A POS will typically work with more than just one device, so you'd need a central data source. The latency to that source and your user speed requirements determines how you'll need to architect it. I've used real time images for low latency or UIs where slow picture fills was acceptable. A POS will usually be on a dedicated network install, so that's good for real time.

If you envision a SaaS multi-tenant solution, then you might need to cache the pictures via a background process - depending on where the images come from and how fast they load. 1200 150x150 images really isn't all that many/that much space. You can store them easily to the local file system on a 'droid, and the SD card works fine for that.

In the spirit of Agile, you probably want to use the simplest solution first - real-time display. Then maybe add caching later if necessary. Then worry about asynchronous background loads if your users need it.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to load them asynchronously in the background from a server. Because  since its a POS system , internet connectivity is a must, so your better off saving images on server & then grabbing them. I personally wouldnt like an application to store that huge number of images on my phone & hog up space.

But the downside is since the no of images is large,loading can take a while. You will need to decide based on what is accpetable & what isnt